# Flask app stops communicating with database using gunicorn and supervisor

Tags: python, mysql, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm running a Flask app on AWS with gunicorn and supervisor. The app itself isn't too complicated, but I am making calls to a MySQL database from Python. Everything works fine for a 12-24 hours, then I stop being able to make calls to the database. Killing supervisor and gunicorn and restarting the app fixes the problem, but I'd like to make this a little more robust. Any thoughts?

Here's how I'm connecting to the database in python:
    `db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", host="localhost", port=3306, db="movie_locations", passwd="mypassword")`

And I make a query like this:
    `db.query(thisquery)`

I run the app with the following command:
    `sudo supervisord -c simple.conf`

Here's my `simple.conf` file:

```
[program:myserver]
command=gunicorn myapp:app -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:80

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/ubuntu/supervisord.log
loglevel=debug
user=root
```

And these are the types of errors I get in the .log file:

```
2014-02-03 07:27:19,320 DEBG fd 6 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 26772040 for <Subprocess at 26713840 with name m\
yserver in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
2014-02-03 07:27:19,320 DEBG fd 8 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 26780448 for <Subprocess at 26713840 with name m\
yserver in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
2014-02-03 07:27:19,321 INFO exited: myserver (exit status 1; not expected)
2014-02-03 07:27:19,321 DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2014-02-03 07:27:20,327 INFO spawned: 'myserver' with pid 13288
2014-02-03 07:27:20,498 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
2014-02-03 07:27:20 [13288] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0

2014-02-03 07:27:20,499 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
2014-02-03 07:27:20 [13288] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 80)

2014-02-03 07:27:20,500 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
2014-02-03 07:27:20 [13288] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.

2014-02-03 07:27:21,501 INFO success: myserver entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-03 07:27:21,502 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
2014-02-03 07:27:21 [13288] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 80)

2014-02-03 07:27:21,502 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
2014-02-03 07:27:21 [13288] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.

2014-02-03 07:27:22,504 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
2014-02-03 07:27:22 [13288] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you communicate database through python? Can you show us your sample database code?

Comment: *When* do you create the database connection? On startup, in a `before_request` handler or at another time? How do you handle concurrent access?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am also facing the same issue with similar setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. The problem was I had naively declared the database cursor as a global variable. Eventually, the connection timed out or otherwise degraded. To fix it, I put the database declaration in a function so that it would close when it went out of scope and would be reestablished upon an additional function call.